# Angular 2: Subscribe to observable truncating service response -- routing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I am practicing with angular 2.x services and routing. I navigate to a URL using the Router and then I'm trying to pass a URL parameter that I get from ActivatedRoute to get a string from WhichnailService service. However, the response from the .subscribe() in the WhichnailComponent only has the last index of the string to be returned.

When I log the Service itself, it has the complete string

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import {WhichnailService} from './whichnail.service';


@Component({
    selector: 'whichnail-component',
    template: `
    <h1> welcome to the Whichnail Component </h1>
    <h1> The nail is {{ nail }} </h1>
    `
}) 
export class WhichnailComponent {
    nail:string;
    selectedNail:number;
    constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, private service: WhichnailService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params
    // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
        .switchMap((params: Params) => this.service.getNail(this.selectedNail = +params['id']))
        .subscribe((nail:string) => this.nail = nail);
    }
}
```

And this is the service itself:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()

export class WhichnailService {
    listOfNails = ["Invalid", "Thumb", "Index", "Middle", "Ring", "Pinky"];

    getNail(index: number):string {
        console.log(index);
        console.log(this.listOfNails[index]);
        return this.listOfNails[index];
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I figured out what was wrong: I needed to return an Observable.of from my service. I am still a little unsure about why, so help/resource would still be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to return an Observable.of from my service.

Because you can only subscribe to an `Observable`. That's why, even to return a plain value which does not requires asynchronous (or observable) process, you need to wrap it with an observable so that it can be subscribed. The way of doing this is by using `Observable.of`

If your service doesn't require an observable operation, you can do *without* it. Just subscribe to your `routeparams` and update the value:

```
ngOnInit(){
 this.route.params
   .subscribe((params: Params) => {
    //assign the value directly
    this.nail = this.service.getNail(this.selectedNail = +params['id'])
   })
}
```

And in your service you **do not** need to wrap it with an `Observable.of`

```
export class WhichnailService {
    listOfNails = ["Invalid", "Thumb", "Index", "Middle", "Ring", "Pinky"];

    getNail(index: number):string {
        return this.listOfNails[index]; //no need to wrap with Observable.of
    }
}
```

Comment: helpful answer!